# How can I prove that $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(B_\varepsilon)} \iiint_{B_\varepsilon} f(x,y,z) \,dV = f(x_0, y_0,z_0)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let be $f$ continuous and $B_\varepsilon$ the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered on the point $(x_0, y_0,z_0)$. Let be $\operatorname{vol}(B_\varepsilon)$ the volume of $B_\varepsilon$. Show that:

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(B_\varepsilon)} \iiint_{B_\varepsilon} f(x,y,z) \, dV = f(x_0, y_0,z_0)$$

Comment: Do you know Lebesgue's differentiation theorem?

Comment: yes, I do know it

Comment: If you are allowed to use that theorem, then this is an immediate consequence an application of that theorem. If not, I will post a hint in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $f(x) - \dfrac{1}{m(B)} \displaystyle\int_B f(y)dy = \dfrac{1}{m(B)} \int_B(f(x) - f(y))dy$. Next, use the fact that $f$ is continuous and consider a ball of radius $\dfrac{\delta}{2}$. Here $m(B)$ refers to the measure of the ball $B$ which is the same as your volume.